# Typing Vuex actions

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuex

I am using Vue3 and Vuex4 with TS.

Let's say my actions look like this in Vuex:

```
 anAction: async (
    { commit, state }: { commit: Commit; state: MyStoreState },
    { parameter1, parameter2 }: { parameter1: string, parameter2: number }
  ) => {
    /* some code */
    commit("...", /* so on so forth */);
  },
```

I am using `mapActions` inside my components to use those actions:

```
/* rest of component code */
methods: {
    ...mapActions(['anAction'])
}
```

However, if I call `this.anAction` from any of my component code, this is its signature:

```
(...args: any[]) => Promise<any>
```

Is there a way to get the correct typing on the mapped action, i.e. the one I defined in my store?

Comment: TS typing is the weak part of options api and Vuex. Not sure if something can be done here in a reasonable way. Pinia and composition can improve this

Comment: I agree that could improve it, but it entails an almost complete rewrite of a pretty large codebase. There isn't a way around this with that vuex and the options API offer?